# How do I access the object that implements UIApplicationDelegate from anywhere in my code?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uikit, uiapplicationdelegate

What is the proper way of accessing a method of my application (object implementing `UIApplicationDelegate`) from anywhere in my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Caleb is right, adding a tip below that saves on typing and increases symmetry between AppKit and UIKit.

If you're a Mac programmer you're probably used to accessing the delegate like so,

```
   [NSApp delegate]
```

In AppKit, NSApp is defined so,

```
   #define NSApp [NSApplication sharedApplication]
```

So to get something similar in iOS do this,

```
   #define UIApp [UIApplication sharedApplication]
```

Then to access the delegate you would do this:

```
   [UIApp delegate]
```

Answer (score 3):

`id<UIApplicationDelegate> delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`

Comment: I'm not really sure what specifying the protocol buys you here.

Comment: I'm just trying to make it obvious that the object you get back could be of any type (id), but it should implement the protocol. If you know the type of the delegate, use that instead. In practice, I'd avoid accessing the app delegate at all if I could. It's usually done to share data between different objects, and there are better ways to do that.

Comment: Caleb I think the App delegate is a great way of combating the over-use of singletons. If I have an object in my application that should be shared across the entire application, I just make it a property of the App delegate. In other classes that need that object define a read-only property that just returns the object from the App delegate.

Comment: Many would agree with you, but I don't. This topic usually comes up in relation to view controllers. I prefer a style where each view controller is given the data it needs  to do its job when it's created.

Comment: @Gaspy1909: A singleton is bad because it's a global in object form. The application delegate is the same thing, just accessed through a singleton rather than being the singleton. And when you use it to access other objects, you're both extending that problem to those objects and violating the Law of Demeter. You should rearrange what owns what if you have no way to access something you need without using singletons (including the application object).

Comment: @peter-hosey: I somewhat agree with you. That's why if I state you should access the object as a read-only property (- (UserData) userData { return [[[UIApplication shareApplication] delegate] userData]; }) It allows you to easily convert your application later, if it becomes of problem. I think using the property to access global data strikes the line between complexity and maintainability. In most client applications I think this works well.

Comment: @peter-hosey It depends on the context of the code and project.